# Error importing Parquet to Redshift: optional int

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, amazon-redshift, parquet

I'm creating a table in Redshift as follows:

```py
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

from sqlalchemy import Column
from sqlalchemy_redshift.dialect import INTEGER, VARCHAR

Base = declarative_base()

class SomeTable(Base):
    __tablename__ = "some_table"

    id = Column(INTEGER, primary_key=True)

    some_column = Column(VARCHAR(128))

# ...
# code that connects to Redshift
# ...

base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

The table in Redshift looks like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE public.some_table (                
    id integer NOT NULL ENCODE az64,              
    some_column character varying(128) ENCODE lzo, 
)                                                 
DISTSTYLE AUTO                                    
SORTKEY ( id );
```

I have a `pandas.DataFrame` with the following schema:

```
id                   int64
some_column          object
dtype: object
```

I create a `.parquet` file and upload it to S3:

```py
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile

from pyarrow import Table, int64, schema, string
from pyarrow.parquet import write_table

with NamedTemporaryFile() as file:
    parquet_table = Table.from_pandas(
        df,
        schema=schema(
            [
                ("id", int64()),
                ("some_column", string()),
            ]
        ),
    )
    write_table(parquet_table, file)

    # ...
    # code to upload file to S3
    # ...
```

Using `parquet-tools inspect`, I get the following schema from the uploaded file:

```
############ file meta data ############
created_by: parquet-cpp-arrow version 10.0.0
num_columns: 2
num_rows: 21
num_row_groups: 1
format_version: 2.6
serialized_size: 3802


############ Columns ############
id
some_column

############ Column(id) ############
name: id
path: id
max_definition_level: 1
max_repetition_level: 0
physical_type: INT64
logical_type: None
converted_type (legacy): NONE
compression: SNAPPY (space_saved: -4%)

############ Column(some_column) ############
name: some_column
path: some_column
max_definition_level: 1
max_repetition_level: 0
physical_type: BYTE_ARRAY
logical_type: String
converted_type (legacy): UTF8
compression: SNAPPY (space_saved: -5%)
```

Finally, I try to upload the file from S3 to Redshift using SQL:

```py
# ...
# code that gets a SQLAlchemy Session
# ...

session.execute(
    f"COPY {SomeTable.__tablename__} "
    + f"FROM '{s3_uri}' "
    + f"IAM_ROLE '{arn_role}' "
    + "FORMAT AS PARQUET;"
)
```

I get the following error:

```
psycopg2.errors.InternalError_: Spectrum Scan Error
DETAIL:  
  -----------------------------------------------
  error:  Spectrum Scan Error
  code:      15007
  context:   File 'https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/bucket/1681141668/some_table.parquet' has an incompatible Parquet schema for column 's3://bucket/1681141668/some_table.parquet.id'. Column type: INT, Parquet schema:
optional int
  query:     2627
  location:  dory_util.cpp:1450
  process:   worker_thread [pid=19137]
  -----------------------------------------------
```

How can I make the Redshift table compatible with the `.parquet` file (or vice-versa)?